# Does the HTML image tag actually blocks the JS main thread in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, browser

There are a lot of articles on the internet suggesting to load images with web worker for performance gains and to free the main thread. ([google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+load+images+with+web+worker))

But I couldn't find any actual references saying that image tags actually blocks the main thread.

I thought browsers are intelligent enough to identify an image tag and understand that it has to render it anyway. This is a common situation. So instead of, needing us adding new web workers for this common problem, browsers could use a separate process/thread/thing to solve this problem in a way that wont block the main thread.

[This article](https://dev.to/trezy/loading-images-with-web-workers-49ap) describes

> Fun fact: `<img>` tags actually block your application load. If you have 100 images on your page, the browser will download all 100 of them before it renders your page.

I couldn't comprehend this. I thought adding [`loading="lazy"`](https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/) was better than the web worker work around.

Comment: I can't remember ever seeing that while browsing, and I browse a lot. My experience has always been that if there are images that aren't downloaded immediately, the browser renders the rest of the page regardless.

Comment: @tao Now I'm not so sure. Try: `<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4e/Pleiades_large.jpg"> <div>more content</div>` with `img { height: 100px }` - the `more content` does seem to appear after the image downloads, check your Network tab. Or maybe something else alters this behavior. I can reproduce it in a Stack Snippet here, but not on JSFiddle

Comment: I think what I'm experiencing with Stack Snippets is due to my Tampermonkey, if I turn it off, the images download asynchronously as expected

Comment: @CertainPerformance The CSS should not be used in such a test as it can visually alter what you perceive as happening first vs. second.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Fun fact: `<img>` tags actually block your application load. If you have
> 100 images on your page, the browser will download all 100 of them
> before it renders your page.*

**That is completely false.** If that were true no one would ever see the text of their web page with empty boxes where the images would be, followed by the images loading in those boxes. The entire point of [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) vs. [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) events is that the HTML elements can be completely parsed before the external page resources have finished downloading and rendering. Additionally, no one would ever need a `load` event on an `img` because, if that article were true, all images would be loaded by the time you saw the page.

=============================================================

While the JavaScript runtime is single threaded, the browser client is not. "Resource files" (any file that is referenced by the .html page being parsed) are downloaded simultaneous to the page being parsed. There may be a maximum amount of resources that the client will download at the same time (years ago in IE the limit was 10 by default, but I think that's been upped since then).

Oftentimes when you load up a web page, you'll see all the text of the page first (because text loads really fast) and the images load after that. It's simply because images take longer to download than text, not that the images wait to begin downloading.

This can be verified by looking at the Network tab of your browser's development tools while a page loads. You'll see a variety of resources being downloaded simultaneously with the page.

Comment: Got it. It'd be nice if you could also include the "Does the HTML image tag blocks the JS main thread?" part in your answer if you know it. So that I can accept the answer.

Comment: @Wajahath HTML parsing isn't handled by the JS runtime, so no. My answer clearly explains that no HTML element blocks any thread.

Comment: It does though. I just added 10MB PNG sprite sheet 100 000px wide to the page and it does block the main thread while decoded, especially noticeable on mobile phone where it gets stuck for a good 5 seconds :)

Comment: @waterplea [sigh] No, it doesn’t. Just because there’s a delay in your Ability to see or interact with the page does not mean that the JavaScript runtime is being blocked. The browser is much more than the JavaScript runtime. Please re-read my answer.